Display only certain category in Output window?
Debug.WriteLine(string? message, string? category) allows selecting a category for the debug message. In my case, I already have many debug statements in my project. I can see the category, but I would like to eliminate the previous debug messages in other categories to focus on the current task.
Visual Studio automatically prepends the category name, so output messages show up in the format "category: message".
Is there a way to filter the Output window to do this, when showing output from "Debug"? There is a context menu to select error messages (exceptions, step category, module load, etc.), but I want to filter by category, and am not finding that option.

Identify Categories: List all the categories you need to manage or display.
Tagging System: Implement a tagging system where each task or item is tagged with a category.that makes to easier filter and find what needed you.

I thought of implementing an Enum, but it would make more sense to do it through Visual Studio if that already exists.
